# Is it possible to write tizen wearable custom launcher?

Tags: tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I just started reading documentation included with wearable sdk and im looking about possibilities to create a custom launcher. Basically I want to write app that can control whole watch, and cannot be uninstalled. Is there any mechanisms in web api that would enable such behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. With web you can't even write custom Simple Clock - only Watch Face is available for  web development.
You could write your custom Tizen and then do whatever you want ;)

Comment: Is it possible to download Tizen for Wearable source and customize it? Only found the full Tizen SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to control the installation and uninstallation of applications on Tizen is by having **platform permission level** (HELP docs: *Tizen Wearable Web App Programming > API References > Device API Reference > Application*)

You can also launch and kill apps using Application API (HELP docs: *Tizen Wearable Web App Programming > API References > Device API Reference > Application*).

So features of an launcher are possible but... no such application type exists.
You could build that kind of app but users will need to run them manually.